# How to give scrolling effect in datalist dropdown?

Tags: html, angular

I am using HTML datalist to show various career paths but my number of options is too long . I wish to give it a scrolling effect. I have searched for it but only thing I found was CSS cannot be applied on datalist. Is it possible to apply styles on datalist using jQuery?

Here is my HTML markup:

```
<input class="form-control searchbar" #input (input)="filterdata(input.value)" [(ngModel)]="homesearch" id="home_ssearch" name="careerr" list="careers" placeholder="Discover more about any career you like" />
<div>
        <datalist class="datalist" id="careers" >
          <option *ngFor = "let career of carrerpathList" value="{{career.title}}" ></option>         
        </datalist>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.scrollable {
  overflow-y: auto !important;  // Use !important only if there is already an overflow style rule for this element and you want to override
}
```

And just apply it like this:

```
<datalist class="datalist scrollable" id="careers" >
     <option *ngFor = "let career of carrerpathList" value="{{career.title}}" ></option>         
</datalist>
```

Hope it helps! ;)

**Update 1:**

I hate inline styles, but let's try it to see if `<datalist>` accepts styles. Try this:

```
<datalist class="datalist scrollable" id="careers" style="overflow-y: auto!important">
```

Comment: @UtkarshGautam I updated. Let's try that and see how it goes. Let me please know if it's getting this style.

Comment: @UtkarshGautam Inspect the element and see if it's accepting the style. Maybe if the style is being accepted we just need to change the CSS rule

Comment: .datalist{ display: none }; thats what it is showing.

Comment: I am not able to right click on the dropdown and inspect I manually from Elements tried to find out what CSS it has got.

Comment: When it eventually shows up (is showing up right?) right click it and select *Inspect* option. Chrome and Firefox are my favourites for inspecting DOM elements.

Comment: Yes I did that but it dosent respond to my right click.

Comment: Firefox by default applies scrollbar in my dropdown list.

Comment: Is there a way to style it using jquerry.

Comment: Or can you suggest someother pluggin that I can use for auto completetion for angular2 application

Comment: @UtkarshGautam Hey good friend! Yesm you can style with jQuery! Using `css()` and `addClass()` . Check this: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

This simple approach works for me:

```
datalist {
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Note: This CSS will apply the scroll effect to all `<datalist>`

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't. This element is an example of a "replaced element", these are OS-dependent and are not part of the HTML/browser. It cannot be styled via CSS.

Instead you can use bootstrap dropdown or any other plugin for the same.

I have used bootstrap for it, you can adjust the height accordingly for e.g,

```
.dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Arham11/cojy8mh3/5/)

Comment: problem with this is, its not searchable. If this has hundred values user has to scroll and look for value one by one

Comment: you need to do some extra work to make bootstrap dropdown searchable.

Comment: I just used HTML datalist, the problem is while editing details later in the profile the input with the list attribute is not populating with data sent from the server. rest of the fields are populating.

Comment: Check out these two links. 
https://gomakethings.com/how-to-create-an-autocomplete-input-with-only-html/
https://gomakethings.com/creating-an-ajax-autocomplete-component-with-html-and-vanilla-js/

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
.datalist {
   height:50px !important;
   max-height:80px !important;
   overflow-y:auto;
   display:block !important;
}
```

Comment: It looks as if initially when the drop down loads it takes the height but then it overflows.

Comment: The initial height for the datalist will be 80px. scroll will be enable if the options are too long .

Comment: It is not excepting any CSS that I try to give.

Comment: change the class name. may be there is a naming conflict , and add the display:block !important to it

Comment: I tried changing the class name but it isnt working. Can we use jquerry to style I guess that will work

Comment: Or can you suggest someother pluggin that I can use for auto completetion for angular2 application

Comment: jst add display:block !important; to the existing class.It works. !important overwrites the default property of hidden to block

Comment: This displays datalist itself, if the datalist is being used as a dropdown for select autosuggestions, it will not style the dropdown.