# Dropdown plus input Text in angularjs and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have a single field which acts as a drop down and also as a input text field , Where user can either select value from drop down or input a text.

I found something similar , below is the code snippet of the same.

```
<input type="text" name="city" list="cityname">
<datalist id="cityname">
  <option value="Boston">
  <option value="Cambridge">
</datalist>
```

How can use the datalist in angular and fetch the options from a rest api call?

refer the below link for working model of datalist plain -->https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to fetch the list of the options from the server and then use [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) on `option` element to populate the list of the options in the template. See the example below:

```js
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module("demo", [])
        .service('CountriesService', ['$http', function CountriesService($http) {
            var countriesService = this;
            var countriesResult = null;

            countriesService.getCountries = getCountries;

            function getCountries() {
                if (!countriesResult) {
                    countriesResult = $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: '//restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all'
                    }).then(function (res) {
                        return res.data;
                    });
                }
                return countriesResult;
            }

            return countriesService;
        }])
        .controller('Demo', ['CountriesService', function Demo(CountriesService) {
            var vm = this;

            vm.$onInit = onInit;
            vm.countryChanged = countryChanged;

            function onInit() {
                CountriesService.getCountries().then(function (res) {
                    vm.countries = res;
                });
            }

            function countryChanged(selectedCountry) {
                console.log(selectedCountry);
            }
        }]);
})(angular);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="Demo as vm">
    <hr/>
    <input type="text" name="country" list="countryname" ng-model='vm.selectedCountry' ng-change="vm.countryChanged(vm.selectedCountry)">
    <datalist id="countryname">
        <option ng-repeat="country in vm.countries track by country.name" value={{::country.name}}></option>
    </datalist>
    <hr/>
    {{vm.selectedCountry}}
</div>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm!! I faced few small issues in mozilla and chrome. I have a big list of dropdown in mozilla all the values are not shown and in chrome i am unable to scroll down.

Comment: [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491711/how-to-give-scrolling-effect-in-datalist-dropdown), maybe it helps you to add scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `ng-submit` on form tag ?

Exemple :

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
```

And on JS code :

```
        $scope.submit = function () {
        ///DO STUFF
    };
```