# How can I limit the visible options in an HTML <input list> dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I needed to limit the number of options in a `select` dropdown, and I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788245/how-can-i-limit-the-visible-options-in-an-html-select-dropdown), which showed a way - using javascript - do it.

But I started to wonder: Is there a way do also limit the number of options in a `input list`

If I wanted to only show three items (and a scroll bar) in this example:

```html
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Google Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Would be there a way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491711/how-to-give-scrolling-effect-in-datalist-dropdown https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482404/how-to-make-a-html-datalist-overflow

Comment: No, you can't style `datalist` as answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693482/is-there-a-way-to-apply-a-css-style-on-html5-datalist-options) question.

Comment: I did a terrible job searching for duplicates, apparently. :)

Comment: That's alright ;)

Comment: Can I just praise you for introducing me to input list? That's so useful!